# Replacement rings/gasket for Rocco jars

Tags: equipment, storage

I see two types of material for replacement gaskets for Rocco jars, silicon and rubber. What would the difference of these materials be if simple used for food storage at room and refrigerator temperatures; not canning? Are they both airtight?

P.S. There is no accurate method other than seller stating food-grade, that the material truly is food-grade?

Comment: Material purity depends what country you're living in. There is such a thing as food grade silicon - distinct from silicon in construction applications where additives affect pliability and curing time. In my opinion there's no reason for a manufacturer to "lie" about this kind of thing, but many harbor distrust of big baddie chemical manufacturers. Nevertheless, in the US, people may be disappointed to know that external oversight is kind of done "at risk". "Food grade" in the US usually means doesn't cause acute illness - tobacco products and alcohol are, for instance, "food grade".

Comment: https://bestsiliconereviews.com/silicone-vs-rubber/ This is a useful overview

Comment: Hey, Adam, that sounds like an answer you could post.